# Allow users to upload account photo in "Sign up form"?

Tags: forms, accounts

I have a **sign up** form ,which contains required fields to create account (Last name ,First name,User role,Email ,password ) ,but I added other stuff that allows user to upload photo for his account ,I found that most of application make this in second step or after open dashbaord.

This is my **Sign up** form ,when the user click on account-photo-image-view , a file chooser will opened.I have these questions :

1-Should I remove this process from the sign up form and add it in dashboard ?

2-If I can save it like this ,should I add a Button to upload Image ?

[image: Form] :

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what this app does? As mentioned by qoba, you need to decide how important it is for people to have a distinctive profile picture. I would share my 2 cents here on the wire -

1. Add some signifier (Maybe just + ) to the profile picture icon, right now it's not intuitive enough for a user to understand that tapping on this will allow them to add a profile picture. Also, don't keep it mandatory to proceed further in case people don't need to have a distinctive profile picture. Allow them to add later on.
2. The current icon looks Male-specific, try to use the general icon.
3. Make users enter the first name first, most of the forms work this way. I am not sure why you want to reinvent?

Comment: What did you with general icon ?

Comment: something like in here  - https://www.ashoka.org/en/topics/environment-0

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the sign up and registration part should be as simple and as minimal as possible. One of the most simplest registrations I have seen is that on groupon. All that is required is your email address.

I would ask only for the absolute required information such as email, password and agreement to terms and conditions(if required).

**Below are the changes I would suggest to the form above**

1. Reduce the number of fields on the registration screen. Contemplate
   each and every field that needs to be filled by the user. Every
   field that is added increases a mental barrier and provides another
   reason for the user to quit the registration process (Currently I
   see that only the email and password should be required ---terms and
   conditions if there are legal bindings for you to show them)
2. Mark the mandatory fields even if you have only 2 fields to be
   entered. It is a good practice to tell the user what is required and
   what to expect
3. Move everything such as First Name, Last Name, Role, Profile picture
   to the profile section
4. If you are in absolute need of the some of the profile information,
   these can be filled out as soon as the email is validated if you are
   asking the users to validate their email. If not then you can log
   the users in and navigate the users to the profile screen as soon as
   they register

We had an even longer sign up screen and when we switched to a registration screen that was much simpler with absolutely the minimal information required (along with changes in the post registration helpful information sent out to setup the profile) we saw **two major positive impacts** of that change

1. There was a significant improvements in our registration rates
2. The number of call center calls for inability to register dropped drastically

It might be an interesting case for testing some of these fields with your user base and draw inferences, pivot and refine further.

Let me know if you would like to discuss further details.

Comment: But all of them are required  ( I had removed picture from this section).

Comment: The question to be asked for each field do you really need this field for registration or do you need this to complete the profile. For example are you going to validate someone using their first name and last name or are you going to use this information to greet someone after they login. If the answer is the field is not required for validation then it is not required for registration.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how important it is for people to have a distinctive profile picture when using your service / app.

Here are some cases where it may be warranted:

- You're building a dating app
- There will be lots of user-to-user interactions with many different users in your product
- There will be group interactions (lists of people are hard to present on small screens, and lists of avatars can be faster to read, but if they're all standard avatars that's not really helpful)

Otherwise you're best saving it for a second step after your registration is done. Consider for example that if the app is to be used in a professional setting, many people don't have a go-to photo that they will be comfortable using as their profile picture with colleagues.